# How can I add an option in the context menu in Windows Explorer to split files by 15 GB chunks?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, zip, 7-zip, archiving

I often need to upload files to Microsoft OneDrive, whose max size per file with my account is 15 GiB.

How can I add an entry in the context menu in Windows Explorer to split files by 15 GB chunks?

Ideally I'd prefer if one could select several files and split each of them by 15 GB chunks at once. But even just splitting 1 file would be convenient.

---

7-zip doesn't have this function by default:

[image]

I don't want to have to manually define the split for each file:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This possible solution involves editing the registry.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type regedit.
2. Open `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\`. Select `shell`.
3. Right-click `shell`, select `New` then `Key`. Name it `Split`.
4. Double-click `Default` and enter `Split to 15GB`.
5. Right-click the key `Split`, select `New` then `Key`. Name it `command`.
6. Double-click `Default` and enter `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe a -v15g "%2%1.zip" "%1"`
7. Right-click the file you want to split. Select `Split into 15GB`.

Comment: Great answer, that's very much! Follow-up question: [How can I add a option in the context menu in Windows Explorer only for files larger than some threshold?](https://superuser.com/q/1544899/116475)

Answer (score 0):

The following simply automates [Reddy Lutonadio](https://superuser.com/users/855367/reddy-lutonadio)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1544528/116475):

Save as a `.reg` the following code, execute it, and restart `explorer.exe`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Split]
@="Split to 15GB"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Split\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zG.exe a -v15g \"%2%1.zip\" \"%1\""
```

You'll see the new `Split to 15GB` entry in the contextual menu:

[image]

(successfully tested on Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Version   10.0.17763 Build 17763 a.k.a. 1809  a.k.a. Redstone 5)

---

To confirm, this is what you should see in `registry`:

[image]

[image]